# Follow another user via Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, chatter

Can anyone tell me how to follow the another user in Salesforce Org?

There are 3 user in my org. Eg.: user1, user2, user3

User3 wanna follow user1, user2
For that how to write vfp;

My VFP:

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="true" showHeader="false">  
   <chatter:feedwithFollowers entityId="{!$User.Id}"/>
   <chatter:follow entityId="**I don't know what to write here**"  />        
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

This questions is a little ambiguous..  My assumption here is that when an user visits the visualforce page they will follow user1, user2.

Suggest using a page action to call a controller method.

The controller method will construct an entitySubscription for user1, user2.

http://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_entitysubscription.htm

You will also need to query to see if the user viewing the page is already following.  Trying to create an entitySubscription where one already exists will result in an error being thrown.

Comment: Can you give me the code for that?

Comment: No I will not provide your code.

Comment: I am new to this. please help !

Comment: I did help.. Look at your other posts it appears you just want people to write your code..  I will provide you the code for $$$  you can contact me at ben@bpirih.com and we can discuss payment via paypal..